# Can i recover deleted intent which is deleted by mistake in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

Hi I really need to recover the intent the i accidentally deleted, is there a way to recovered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've previously used the [Dialogflow Export](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-settings#export) or [Dialoflow Versions/Environments](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-versions#publish_a_version_in_a_new_environment) to save a copy of the previous agent, unfortunately there is no recover functionality.

For this reason, it's always advisable to have separate agents per environment (ie one for `dev` and one for `prod`) so that any changes you make don't affect any production-systems. If you don't want to do this, then excessive use of the export functionality may be your best option to prevent this in future.

You *may* be able to salvage an old intent by digging around in the Dialogflow History or even better the Stackdriver logs (if you've had those enabled) - but there's no built-in functionality for retrieving deleted intents.